# Add two sublists in Suitelet side by side

Tags: netsuite

I wanted to add two sublists side by side in netsuite using suitelet. however, when I do that the sublists appear top and bottom.

Is there any solution for this.I want the output as in the screenshot.[image]

> var newTab = form.addTab({ id : 'matchedtab', label : 'Matched' });

```
var nMatchedList =    form.addSublist({ id: 'custpage_matched', type: serverWidget.SublistType.LIST, label: 'Matched',tab:'matchedtab' });
nMatchedList.addRefreshButton();
nMatchedList.addField({ id : 'custpage_tr_cleared', type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT, label : 'Cleared' });
nMatchedList.addField({ id : 'custpage_tr_name', type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT, label : 'Name' });                     nMatchedList2 =       form.addSublist({ id: 'custpage_matched2', type: serverWidget.SublistType.LIST, label: 'Matched',tab:'matchedtab' });
nMatchedList2.addRefreshButton();
nMatchedList2.addField({ id : 'custpage_tr_cleared2', type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT, label : 'Cleared' });
nMatchedList2.addField({ id : 'custpage_tr_name2', type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT, label : 'Name' });
```

Used this code to get output like in the given screenshot but the sublist gets added vertically.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this is the default behavior of the serverWidget module

Comment: No. by default the sublists are not added in single tab and side-by-side