# Add two different sublists in netsuite side by side

Tags: netsuite

I wanted to add two different sublists side by side in netsuite using suitelet. however, when I do that the sublists appear top and bottom.

Is there any solution for this.I wanted to have the output as in the screenshot in the link.
[Add two sublists in Suitelet side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006488/add-two-sublists-in-suitelet-side-by-side/57099550#57099550)

> var newTab = form.addTab({ id : 'matchedtab', label : 'Matched' });

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add two sublists in Suitelet side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006488/add-two-sublists-in-suitelet-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0):

By adding tab in the sublist should solve your issue. Also adding field groups will make the form more organised

```
  form.addSublist({
                        id : 'sublistidentire',
                        type : serverWidget.SublistType.INLINEEDITOR,
                        label : ' Test',
                         tab    : 'matchedtab'
                    });
```